# Customize django drf JWT response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

*I followed the drf documentation to customize response. I want to get userdata with JWT but i cannot.
Thanks you*

```
  #settings:
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 
    'spauser.views.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    #views
    def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
        #if I remove spauser, django returns an error: SpaUser matching query does not exist.

        spa_user = SpaUser.objects.get(email= 'test@test.com')
        return {
            'token': token,
            'user': SpaUserSerializer(spa_user, context={'request':request}).data
        }


#serialisers:
    class SpaUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        date_joined = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
        birthdate = serializers.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y", input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y',], )
        # birthdate = serializers.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y", input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y',])
        # birthdate = serializers.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)


        class Meta(object):
            model = SpaUser
            fields = ('id', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname',
                      'date_joined', 'password',  'birthdate','country')
            extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

and my models.py

```
class SpaUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    country= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    jwt_secret = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)

    objects = SpaUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

test@test.com is an example and I tried all the forums but i not found solutions.

Answer (score 0):

replace just JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER with JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER in settings